# Error: socket hang up when building android app using Expo

Tags: android, json, react-native, npm, expo

After running `exp build:android` the cmd outputs this:

```
[exp] Making sure project is set up correctly...
[exp] Your project looks good!
[exp] Checking if current build exists...

[exp] No currently active or previous builds for this project.

? Would you like to upload a keystore or have us generate one for you?
If you don't know what this means, let us handle it! :)
 false
[exp] Unable to find an existing exp instance for this directory, starting a new one...
[exp] Starting React Native packager...
[exp] Scanning folders for symlinks in C:\Users\Ansis\Desktop\Pašapmācība\Test\node_modules (39ms)
[exp] Loading dependency graph.
[exp] Tunnel connected.
[exp] Publishing...
[exp] Dependency graph loaded.
[exp] Building iOS bundle
[exp] Error: socket hang up
[exp] Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.
```

Almost noone has experienced this error and those that have, fixed it by adding

```
"packagerOpts": {
      "nonPersistent": true,
}
```

to app.json. Well... For me that changed nothing. If I could see a more verbose output, maybe I'd understand where to look, but I don't even understand what it means by `Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env`.

Here's the app.json:

```
 {
   "expo": {
    "name": "Vards",
    "icon": "android.png",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "slug": "vards",
    "sdkVersion": "25.0.0",
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.kojas.vards"
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.kojas.vards"
    },
    "packagerOpts": {
      "nonPersistent": true,
    }
   }
 }
```

And the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Test",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest-expo": "25.0.0",
    "react-native-scripts": "1.11.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.2.0"
  },
  "main": "./node_modules/react-native-scripts/build/bin/crna-entry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native-scripts start",
    "eject": "react-native-scripts eject",
    "android": "react-native-scripts android",
    "ios": "react-native-scripts ios",
    "test": "node node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "^25.0.0",
    "react": "16.2.0",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-25.0.0.tar.gz"
  }
}
```

`exp start` works fine. So does `npm start`.
Thanks.

Edit:
This is the output after setting EXPO_DEBUG to true:

```
[exp] Dependency graph loaded.
[exp] Warning: Not using the Expo fork of react-native. See https://docs.expo.io/.
[exp] Building iOS bundle
[exp] Error: socket hang up
[exp] RequestError: Error: socket hang up
    at new RequestError (C:\Users\Ansis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:14:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (C:\Users\Ansis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:87:29)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\Ansis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:46:31)
    at self.callback (C:\Users\Ansis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\request\request.js:186:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Request.onRequestError (C:\Users\Ansis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\exp\node_modules\request\request.js:878:8)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at Socket.socketOnEnd (_http_client.js:423:9)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the problem.
It turns out that the crash was caused by unicode characters in the name of a directory the project was in.

Changing this
`C:\Users\Ansis\Desktop\Pašapmācība\Test\node_modules`

To this
`C:\Users\Ansis\Desktop\Prog\Test\node_modules`
Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

To get a more informative error message, set your env var while running your `exp` command (ie) `EXPO_DEBUG=true exp start`

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr:**

Try this: `echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

**Long version**

Okay, so we sussed out our iteration of this problem... our error was similar, but was also reporting an `ENOSPC` error code that was critical in solving the problem. It was fixed by running this line before the publish:

`echo 'fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288' | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p`

`inotify` is the system that `watchman` (a file watcher made by Facebook) uses, and `watchman` is used by Expo. It appears for Travis we would hit the limit of watches and report we had no more space, but actually we just ran out of file descriptors. The line above increases that amount. [More here](https://github.com/guard/listen/wiki/Increasing-the-amount-of-inotify-watchers#the-technical-details). You could also probably try installing `watchman`, but that seemed pretty difficult to do on Ubuntu and the above command worked for us so whatever.

In our particular case, we were using default Travis builds, which it turns out runs on Ubuntu 14. It didn't particularly like the command above, so we switched to using Ubuntu 16 (Xenial) and had to enable `sudo` mode. So, for Travis folks, here's the salient details in our `.travis.yml` file:

```
dist: xenial

# We needed to specify PostgreSQL 10 once we switched to Ubuntu 16
# you might need this as well
addons:
  postgresql: "10"

# then add the script however you want
```

We also noticed that it would choke when we used the `&&` with the command, so we split it into two separate operations:

```
    echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
    sudo sysctl -p
```

Hope this is helpful to other people!